# How to force image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges on all images in firefox

Tags: firefox, images, anti-aliasing

I was wondering if it's possible to force -moz-crisp-edges in firefox for all images? Or how do I disable anti-aliasing for images in firefox?

Essensially, this is what I'm looking for:

[image: Comparison]

*If it's not easy to see the difference, open them in a new tab, and click to zoom to 1:1 pixel match to your monitor*

Maybe there is a way to only disable anti-aliasing on downscaled high resolution images? (when the pixels of the image is smaller than the pixels on the monitor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it this way:

- Find your Firefox profile folder in
  *Help > More Iroubleshooting Information*, field "Profile Folder",
  or open it with the *Open Folder* button
- From the profile folder, open the `chrome` sub-folder
  (or create it if it doesn't exist)
- From the `chrome` sub-folder, open the file `userContent.css` in a text editor
- Add the following line (old and new options) to the file and save it:

  ```
    img { image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; image-rendering: crisp-edges; }
  ```
- Restart Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

1. On the address bar, type `about:config`, search for `gfx.text.disable-aa`.
2. Change it from `false` to `true`.
3. Restart Firefox for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This config only applies to font as far as I can see. Images are not affected by this change. I updated my question to clear up what I'm asking for